# Check if acces is blocked for MGET/MPUT

Tags: sql-server, mget

I am trying to use the MPUT/MGET scripts as shown in:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170393/Download-file-s-from-FTP-Server-using-Command-thro
But i cant get it to work, is there a way to check if you have enought acces to be able to automate ftp through SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

This script builds OS command and runs it using Sql Server `xp_cmdshell` system stored proc. To check current permission to run `xp_cmdshell` run

```
EXEC sp_configure;
```

without parameters and find the row with the `name` = 'xp_cmdshell'.
If you need to enable it see [how to enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) `xp_cmdshell`.